# All Ports in Use after High Sierra Update

Tags: terminal, development, macports, high-sierra

I'm a developer and I have a project built with a task runner called Gulp, when I try to launch it via command line I get an error saying that the port is in use (3000). I then changed it to all other ports I could think off and still the same error.

Need to work on this project, anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: `lsof -i | grep 'TCP.*LIST'`should tell you what is using all your ports

Answer (score 1):

Ok solved it...

Not sure which one of these fixed it, but opened Xcode and accepted the agreement (or run `sudo xcodebuild -license accept`). I then ran `brew update` then `brew upgrade node` and then `npm rebuild node-sass --force-` to rebuild.

It still wasn't working so I finally changed the order in which I was putting tasks in Gulp and it is now fixed...